# Given $X_1,\dots,X_n\sim\mathrm{N}(0,1)$ independent continuous random variables show that $X_n, X_1+\cdots+X_{n-1}$ are independent

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

I have been trying to solve the following probability question to no avail and I would like some help or a nudge in the right direction.

Given $X_1,\dots,X_n\sim\mathrm{N}(0,1)$ independent continuous random variables. Let $X=X_n$ and $Y=X_1+\cdots+X_{n-1}$ show that $X,Y$ are independent.

Logically it makes sense for me that $X,Y$ would be independent, yet I am struggling to show so formally.
What I know and can show is that $Y\sim\mathrm{N}(0,n-1)$ but other than that I am struggling showing that those two continuous variables are actually independent.

Comment: More general result: $\sigma (X_n)$ is independent of $\sigma (X_1,X_2,...,X_{n-1})$. No need for any assumptions on  distributions.

Comment: @geetha290krm I have changed the question as I have noticed that I wrote commas instead of addition regarding $Y=X_1+\cdots+X_{n-1}$.

Comment: What you are asking is still a very special case of what I wrote in my comment.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for the response, sadly I haven't meant the $\sigma$ function while studying probability. Is it the sigmoid function where $\sigma(x)=1-\frac{1}{1+e^{x}}$? If so how would we go about expanding it to more than one input?

Comment: No, $\sigma(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1})$ is not a function, is the sigma-algebra generated by $X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#%CF%83-algebra_generated_by_a_function